# Excel - Extracting parts of a string with an undefined amount of characters?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

Lets say I have 4 columns named "Street number", "Street name", "Suburb" and "State", and three plaintext sentences: "10 magic road sunshine VIC", "105 calder street taylors lakes VIC" and "3 new road airdale QLD".

Right now, I add in special characters between the sections and get it to extract between those, but that's pretty inefficient. Is there anyway to sort though the data and extract the required bits for each column without modifying the data?

Comment: I don't think there is a way. As a human, I can see that the first 'word' will be the street number, and maybe infer that the next couple of words are the street name, but that's because I know `road` and `street` are synonymous. Though I suppose one could make a macro that would do a passable job at this.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. You need human brain power to identify if the words belong in the street name or the suburb, and even humans might need help doing that if they are unfamiliar with the locations. There is no logic that can be applied that magically makes that distinction.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is generally referred to as "address breakdown" - companies get paid good money for developing algorithms which automate this process, and those algorithms usually require separators between different address parts, and are based heavily on official address products - such as UK [Postcode Address File (PAF)](http://www.poweredbypaf.com/end-user/products/data-products/paf-raw-data/)

However, a possible alternative - provided you don't have too many addresses, and don't need to do this operation very often - might be to use [Google Geocoding Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

You feed it address and the output is in xml, with qualified address parts: [Example](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?region=au&address=602%20EUREKA%20STREET%20BALLARAT%20VIC&sensor=false)

There are many ways you could use that, but I quite like to couple it with google sheets [`ImportXML` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en), like so:

[image: address geocoding using google sheets and google geocode api]